# immutable js update deep structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability, immutable.js

I'm getting an 'invalid keypath' error trying to update my structure:

```
state = fromJS({
  cmsData: {
    "pages": [
      {
        "name": "page1",
        "content": {
          "header": "Example header",
          "intro": "Example intro",
          "body": "Example body",
        }
      }
      ...
}
```

I'm trying to update the values in the pages array, using this:

```
state.setIn(['cmsData', 'pages', index, 'content', title], value)
```

index being a number, title a string and value also a string.

I can create a new item instead by doing:

```
state.setIn(['pages', index, 'content', title], value)
```

however as soon as I try to access the main 'cmsData' object then I get an error.

**------UPDATE------**

I'm initially setting the cmsData object rather than it being initial state

```
state.set('cmsData', data)
```

If i do have the object as the initial state, it works fine. However trying to update after it's been set produces invalid keypath

**-----SOLUTION-----**

Instead of setting the initial data, I used mergeDeep which worked!

```
state.mergeDeep({ 'cmsData': data })
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please recheck again? I tried your code and it seems to be working fine.

```
var state = Immutable.fromJS({
    cmsData: {
   "pages": [
      {
        "name": "page1",
        "content": {
          "header": "Example header",
          "intro": "Example intro",
          "body": "Example body",
        }
    }
  ]
 }});
```

I just executed this statement and it returned me an expected object.

Here is the [link to jsbin](https://jsbin.com/lihucodeje/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: See update for more info! I'm actually setting the cmsData object before trying to update it, rather than that object being the initial state. Apologies for not being very clear!

Answer (score 0):

Your new item creation setIn seems to elide the `cmsData` level. Not sure why that would affect the other accesses, but maybe you haven't created what you thought you have, so it's erroring when the item doesn't exist at that keypath (ie. within cmsData)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the initial data, I used mergeDeep which worked!

```
state.mergeDeep({ 'cmsData': data })
```